# Как отобразить один и тот же элемент в разных местах?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Подскажите как отобразить один и тот же элемент в разных местах.
Надо сделать в меню чекбокс и точно такой же чекбокс в контекстном меню.

Comment: Вы не можете отобразить _один и тот же_ элемент в разных местах. Вы можете лишь отобразить одинаковые элементы. Для синхронизации состояния подключите к ним одну и ту же VM.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы можете воспользоваться [стилями](http://professorweb.ru/my/WPF/binding_and_styles_WPF/level11/11_1.php), или создать свой [UserControl](http://professorweb.ru/my/WPF/Template/level18/18_5.php)

Answer (score 0):

Ну, например, создайте статический хелпер, возвращающий ваш чекбокс.

```
public static class Helper
{
    public CheckBox _cb;
    public static CheckBox GetCheckBoxForMenu
    {
        get
        {
            _cb = new CheckBox();
            _cb.Text = "text";
            _cb.CheckedChanged += (s,e) => {
                //handler
            }
            return _cb;
        }
    }
}
```

И добавляйте в любые меню или куда-нибудь `Helper.GetCheckBoxForMenu`

Comment: @Макс Жуков: это как-то чересчур в духе WinForms.

Тем более, нехорошо, когда getter возвращает каждый раз новый объект.